# Docker Volumes - very slow run-Command

Tags: docker, containers, bind, coreos, volumes

I have a Docker container which used to save all data in a dedicated volume `data` to be persistent. That volume was created using the docker volume create command. I Have roughly 1,5 M files in the volume.

When i run a fresh container and want to bind the volume to it using `-v`, this takes an unbelievable long time ~ 3+ hours...

```
    docker run --name freshname -d -p 3838:3838 -v data:/home/pub myimg/own
```

What is the preferred way to handle so many files or is there a better way to persist the files?

I am running Docker 1.9.1 on coreOS 899.15.0 stable.

Comment: Does it take the same amount time if you directly mount the folder?

Comment: No strangely not, when i mount the directory directly with `-v /var/lib/docker/volumes/data:/home/pub` it is blazing fast

Comment: This looks like a bug in the `volume` implementation. You should file a bug report on their github repo https://github.com/docker/docker

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue?